# Result of Url.Action() when Area is used in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm reading Microsoft documentation where it explains about the usage of `Area` for routing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#areas.

There is 1 part I can't understand.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapAreaRoute("duck_route", "Duck",
        "Manage/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute("default", "Manage/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Namespace4
{
    [Area("Duck")]
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult GenerateURLInArea()
        {
            // Uses the 'ambient' value of area
            var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home"); 
            // returns /Manage
            return Content(url);
        }

        public IActionResult GenerateURLOutsideOfArea()
        {
            // Uses the empty value for area
            var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" }); 
            // returns /Manage/Home/Index
            return Content(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is inside `GenerateURLInArea()` action, it returns `/Manage` whereas in `GenerateURLOutsideOfArea()` it returns `/Manage/Home/Index`?

Comment: Plase, post code with text, not images

Comment: @Dani updated to text

Comment: @muhihsan I follow the sample but get an opposite result. Do you get the same result as me ?

Comment: @itminus I just tried and it's true that I got the opposite result. It makes sense then. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@itminus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10091607/itminus) highlighted that the results showed the opposite when it was executed. I've also confirmed that it is true.

So this should be the expected behavior

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Namespace4
{
    [Area("Duck")]
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult GenerateURLInArea()
        {
            // Uses the 'ambient' value of area
            var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home"); 
            // returns /Manage/Home/Index
            return Content(url);
        }

        public IActionResult GenerateURLOutsideOfArea()
        {
            // Uses the empty value for area
            var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" }); 
            // returns /Manage
            return Content(url);
        }
    }
}
```

This actually makes more sense :)

[@itminus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10091607/itminus) also has raised a ticket for this fix https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12221/